# Email is not received when FeedItem body is modified through trigger

Tags: trigger, email, feeditem, chatter-feed

I have a trigger which modifies the content of chatter feed on a particular object (`Position__c`).

Code:

```
trigger FeedItemBodyModify on FeedItem (before insert,before update) {

    for(FeedItem fi : Trigger.new)
    {
        if('Position__c' == String.valueOf(fi.ParentId.getSObjectType())){
            fi.body = '<p>'+fi.body+' Attached Signature </p>';
            system.debug(' body : '+fi.body);
        }
    }
}
```

Here when I tag someone to a post in any other object except `Position__c`, I am able to get email from salesforce. But when I tag on `Position__c`, though the content is modified, I am not receiving any email.

Can anyone tell me why is it so? or do I have to enable some feature which would treat it the same way like other chatter feeds?

Comment: I have 'Mentions me in a post' enable and I receive emails when I am tagged on other object chatter feeds. But not for Position__c.

Answer (score 1):

Found the link which says modifying body won't send email.

[developer.salesforce.com/..](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)

If you use an Apex trigger to modify the Body of a FeedItem object, all mentions hyperlinks are converted to plain text. The mentioned users don't get email notifications.

Comment: You may want to try this workaround: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/06/preserving-mentions-triggers.html

Comment: Thanks Alouie. I tried this yesterday and it works fine. I want to know if there is any upgrade done to this in 2016 releases, so that we don't have to use service to manipulate and can directly manipulate in before triggers.

Comment: No, there's nothing planned in the near future to be able to do it directly.

Comment: Hi @alouie, Posted a new question regarding the chatter feed, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111443/connectapi-chatterfeeds-limit-handling-in-trigger . Hope you could help me.