# NoAccessException on ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.updateFeedElement : line 706 column 1

Tags: exception, connect-api

Urgent Help Needed:

I am getting exception while updating a chatter feed using ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds class.

I am not getting it regularly but for some specific users under a particular custom profile i am seeing this error.

Need help in figuring out what is the field in the profile or org level that is  controlling this.

```
 

trigger FeedItemBodyModify on FeedItem (after insert) {

    List fiIds = new List(); 
    for(FeedItem fi : Trigger.new)
    {
        if('Position__c' == String.valueOf(fi.ParentId.getSObjectType())){
            fiIds.add(fi.Id);
        }

    }

    if(null != fiIds && fiIds.size() > 0){
        String commID = Network.getNetworkId();
        ConnectApi.BatchResult[] feeds = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementBatch(commID, fiIds);

        for (ConnectApi.BatchResult result : feeds) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Object theResult = result.getResult();
                if (theResult instanceof ConnectApi.FeedItem) {
                    ConnectApi.FeedItem item = (ConnectApi.FeedItem) theResult;   
                    ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = ConnectApiHelper.createFeedItemInputFromBody(item.body);

                    ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
                    textInput.text = 'Disclaimer: Modified in a trigger.';

                    ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput lineTextInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
                    lineTextInput.text = '---';

                    ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput blankTextInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
                    blankTextInput.text = ' ';

                    ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput markupBeginInput = new ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput();
                    markupBeginInput.markupType = ConnectApi.MarkupType.Paragraph;

                    ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput markupEndInput = new ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput();
                    markupEndInput.markupType = ConnectApi.MarkupType.Paragraph;


                    input.body.messageSegments.add(markupBeginInput);
                    input.body.messageSegments.add(blankTextInput);                     
                    input.body.messageSegments.add(markupEndInput);
                    input.body.messageSegments.add(markupBeginInput);
                    input.body.messageSegments.add(lineTextInput);                     
                    input.body.messageSegments.add(markupEndInput);
                    input.body.messageSegments.add(textInput);

                    System.debug(input.body.messageSegments);

                    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.updateFeedElement(commID, item.id, input);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the "Edit my own posts" profile setting.

From the [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/06/preserving-mentions-triggers.html):

> In order for this to work, the “Allow users to edit posts and
>   comments” Chatter setting must be on, and the “Edit my own posts” user
>   profile permission must be enabled for all users who post to Chatter.
>   This is very important. Any users who don’t have permission to edit
>   their own posts will see errors when they attempt to post.

For more info, see the [release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_chatter_feeds_edit_posts.htm).

**Edit :**
if 'Moderate Chatter' is enabled, by default user gets privilege to edit a chatter post. So either **'Moderate Chatter'** or **'Edit my own posts'** must be **checked** for the profile in order to update chatter feed from trigger.

Comment: But there are other user who does not have that check enable, and code is working fine with them.  They don't have any permission set as well.

Comment: It seems if 'Moderate Chatter' is checked then 'Edit my own posts' is not required. I mean it overrides.So if 'Moderate Chatter' or 'Edit my own posts' is checked, the code will work fine. Thanks for your quick response.